# Error 0x80070005: Access Denied when running "Hyper-V Host Compute Service"

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyper-v

I am using Windows 11 Pro version 22H2 with OS Build `22621.1555`

I have a working WSL2 but suddenly after booting up the WSL would not start. So I dig up and checked the Hyper-V services.

Apparently the "Hyper-V Host Compute Service" is not running.

[image]

I tried to start it manually but it fails to run. I checked the 'Event Viewer' to see what's causing it:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          20/04/2023 12:08:28 pm
Event ID:      7023
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      WINDOWS
Description:
The Hyper-V Host Compute Service service terminated with the following error: 
General access denied error
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7023</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-04-20T04:08:28.7253351Z" />
    <EventRecordID>194867</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="1148" ThreadID="10624" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>WINDOWS</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Hyper-V Host Compute Service</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">%%2147942405</Data>
    <Binary>76006D0063006F006D0070007500740065000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I've checked permissions such as:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Virtualization.`

[image]

What other ways I can check and debug why Hyper-V won't run? And btw, the Hyper-V features are all on.

[image]

Comment: And when trying to connect to Hyper-V local machine server through the Hyper-V manager: "An error occurred while attempting to connect to server "WINDOWS". Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server. Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on the computer's WINDOWS because the object was not found. The object might have been deleted, verify that the Virtual Machine Management service on the computer is running."

Answer (score 2):

Had this same issue, this is what fixed it:

- Open "Windows Security"
- Click on "App and Browser Control"
- Click on "Exploit Protection Settings"
- Make sure "Control flow guard (CFG)" is set to "On by default"
- Next, go to the "Program Settings" Tab on the same page and check if "vmcompute.exe" is listed, if it is, remove it.
- Reboot